# Spring webapp: how to best setup JDBC connections to single DB such that the DB username on the connections are not uniform?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

For example, I have webservices A and B exposed by a Spring Java webapp running in a single Tomcat instance.

If a client calls A, I want to service that request by hitting database DB using a JDBC connection that is configured with database username u1.  If the client calls B, hit database DB with JDBC connection configured with username u2.

Let's say that the use case is that username u1 and u2 have different permissions in the database, and I need to route to the correct connection to service a given webservice request.

Comment: You have a different url for each method and ask for a connection?

Answer (score 0):

I will go with create different 2 different connection with 2 different user.
So that can be easily created same connection url and u will 2 pair user/password one for u1 and u2.

Comment: That much is obvious since it would require two different connections.  The question I was trying to get at is regarding the best way to use Spring to manage this.  Say for instance I wanted to use connection pooling.  How to manage different pools?  How to manage switching logic to one pool or the other.  Does Spring have anything to draw upon here?

Comment: you can could be create 2 different bean different connection bean for each of it, so if you use like c3po : <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
 <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
 <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
 <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
 <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

Comment: can you use the above and have factory design pattern to show correct datasources.